# GLSL equivalent of HLSL clip()?

Tags: glsl

The HLSL `clip()` function is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I intend to use this for alpha cutoff, in OpenGL. Would the equivalent in GLSL simply be

```
if (gl_FragColor.a < cutoff)
{
    discard;
}
```

Or is there some more efficient equivalent?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OpenGL has no such function. And it doesn't need one.

> Or is there some more efficient equivalent?

The question assumes that this conditional statement is less efficient than calling HLSL's `clip` function. It's very possible that it's *more* efficient (though even then, it's a total micro-optimization). `clip` checks if the value is less than 0, and if it is, discards the fragment. But you're not *testing* against zero; you're testing against `cutoff`, which probably isn't 0. So, you must call `clip` like this (using GLSL-style): `clip(gl_FragColor.a - cutoff)`

If clip is not directly support by the hardware, then your call is equivalent to `if(gl_FragColor.a - cutoff < 0) discard;`. That's a math operation *and* a conditional test. That's slower than just a conditional test. And if it's not... the driver will almost certainly rearrange your code to do the conditional test that way.

The only way the conditional would be slower than `clip` is if the hardware had specific support for `clip` *and* that the driver is too stupid to turn `if(gl_FragColor.a < cutoff) discard;` into `clip(gl_FragColor.a - cutoff)`. If the driver is that stupid, if it lacks that basic pinhole optimization, then you've got *bigger* performance problems than this to deal with.

In short: don't worry about it.